# retain drop down entries on going to another form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form this sort in my application

```
  <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
<% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

      <div class="col-md-12">
       <div id="customs-form">
           <span class="badge">1</span>
          <%= f.label "Select your model location*" %>
          <%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :formatted_display, { prompt: true }, :required => true,  :class => 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">2</span>
          <%= f.label "Select Your model" %>
          <%= f.select :performer_id, grouped_options_for_select(Location.order(:name).map{ |group| [group.name, group.performers.map{ |performer| [performer.first_name, performer.id, {'data-whitelabel_amount'=>performer.white_label.w_markup, 'data-thumb' => performer.profile_thumb_url,'data-id'=>performer.white_label.id, 'data-admin' => performer.white_label.markup.price }] } ] }), { prompt: true},  required: true, class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">3</span>
          <%= f.label "SELECT YOUR CATEGORY" %>
          <%= f.select :clip_category_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.clip_category_performers.map{ |c| [c.clip_category.name, c.clip_category.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }), { prompt: true},  required: true, class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">4</span>
          <%= f.label "SELECT THE DURATION" %>
          <%= f.select :duration_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.duration_performers.map{ |c| [c.duration.time, c.duration.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }),{ prompt: true},  required: true, class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">5</span>
          <%= f.label "SELECT THE QUALITY" %>
          <%= f.select :quality_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.quality_performers.map{ |c| [c.quality.name , c.quality.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }), { prompt: true},  required: true,  class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>

          <span class="badge">6</span>
          <%= f.label "SELECT DELIVERY TIME" %>

          <%= f.select :delivery_time_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.delivery_time_performers.map{ |c| [c.delivery_time.duration, c.delivery_time.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }), { prompt: true},  required: true,  class: 'chosen-select order_form' %>
        <span class="badge">7</span>

        <%= f.label "Write your description"%>

             <% if session[:from_site] %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :affiliate_id, :value=>@prev_website_id%>
     <%end %>
        <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 4, :cols => 60, maxlength: 999, :class => "order_desc order_form form-control" %>
        <span id="remainingC"><p class="help-block">Content limited to 999 characters, remaining: 999</p></span>
        <%= f.hidden_field :total, value: "", id: "order_total"%>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => current_user.email%>
        <% end %>
        <div class="actions" >
          <h4 class="alert1"><p class ="help-block">*Please buy credits before you order as customer</p></h4>
          <%= f.button :"ORDER NOW", :class => "btn btn-lg btn-marketing" %>
        </div>

    </div>
     <!-- <div class="actions" onclick="check()">-->
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is to create an order in my application. The user will have to login before he does this. So if he redirects if he has not to the login page all the selection in the same page is lost. I tried using session varibles but read that they are not supposed to be used in views. Then how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sessions most certainly can be used in views, but I suppose what you read was that they shouldn't be called "naked" (I.E session[:your_params]), because MVC conventions mean they should be defined in the controller

Comment: I can't see `form_for` or `form_tag` defined anywhere? Are you sure you're defining your form? To give a better answer, I'd love to be able to see how you're creating the form

Comment: Ya @RichPeck it is right according to the conventions. Also I was not sure how to modify its value using javascript